# Wrong ELF class when trying to load a C DLL in Python

Tags: python, c, python-2.7, ctypes

C file : data.c

```
    int aa[3] = {10, 20, 30};

    int* my_func()
    {
      return aa;
    }
```

---

Create .so
`>> gcc -c -Wall -Werror -fpic data.c`
`>> gcc -shared -o libdata.so data.o`

---

python file: data.py

```py
    import ctypes
    f = ctypes.CDLL('./libdata.so').my_func
    f.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)
    print [i for i in f().contents]
```

Command to execute:
`>> python data.py`

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "data.py", line 11, in <module>
    f = ctypes.CDLL('./libdata.so').my_func
  File "/app/vbuild/RHEL6-x86_64/python/2.7.9/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: ./libdata.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

Comment: 64-bit python, 32-bit library?

Comment: And don't you need to tell python how many elements are in the array somehow?

Comment: What are the commands to build the .so in 64-bit?

Comment: Compiling with `-m64`, depending on your setup.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the number of items in the array, the following works:

```
$ cat data.py
import ctypes
f = ctypes.CDLL('./libdata.so').my_func
f.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int*3)
print([x for x in f().contents])

$ python data.py 
[10, 20, 30]
```

Comment: I highly doubt this will solve the problem, since the OP is using a 32-bit DLL with a 64-bit Python interpreter, which is causing the error. As you can see in the Traceback, the error occurs on line 2, and the first two lines of your solution are exactly the same. You might be right about the rest though, so you probably have already answered the follow-up question in advance ;-)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I've tested using both 64-bit DLL and python. And the *3 is needed because otherwise only the first value (10) is obtained. Sadly I don't have a fix for the other issue. I used the exact gcc comands provided in the question and the library was built without problem.